# Enforcement of Vermont's Quarantine Restrictions

Tags: rental-property, covid-19, travel, interstate-travel, vermont

I am wondering if anyone has some insight into any enforcement or penalties that may be levied against someone who is caught breaking Vermont's [cross-state-travel](https://accd.vermont.gov/covid-19/restart/cross-state-travel) COVID guidelines, or against someone hosting them in a short-term lodging.

Specifically, outsiders may not share lodging with non-household members, and must quarantine for some period of time either before or after entering Vermont.

I'm asking this from the perspective of an AirBnB host. If I have guests planning to stay at one of my properties, do I have any legal exposure if I do not enforce guests are complying with Vermont's guidelines?

I found [this enforcement article](https://vsp.vermont.gov/covid19/stayhome_enforcement) on the government website, which seems to indicate that they are relying exclusively on voluntary compliance.

1. > In instances where police officers observe or are made aware of potential violations of Gov. Scott’s orders, law enforcement is encouraged to speak with the proprietor, staff, or group, provide a reminder of the new requirements, and assess voluntary compliance.
2. > the orders do not establish cause to initiate a motor vehicle stop or detain people for questioning about their travel.
3. > informing and educating those encountered in violation of the order about the mechanisms that may apply, could prove helpful

With that reading, it seems that there are no legal repercussions for breaking Vermont's guidelines, either fines or expulsion or else... As such, it seems that I (the AirBnB host) am also clear of any actual liability for guests breaking these regulations.

Anyone have any insight on this? Should I be more concerned/thorough when vetting guests to come stay in my property? I deep-clean the residence between guests (per AirBnB guidelines), so am not concerned about any contamination impacting future guests.

Thanks!

Comment: Downvoter, please explain?

Comment: One of the big reasons for people to visit Vermont at this time is to ski. There has been mention on TV stations of ski resorts saying they will restrict the future skiing of people who they discover are violating the COVID-19 regulations. I found the [following passage at this part of the Killington web site](https://www.killington.com/plan-your-trip/getting-here/20-21-winter-experience/vermont-visitor-requirements). Click on "OUT OF STATE VISITOR REQUIREMENTS" to see the passage. > Failure to comply with the state’s travel and quarantine policy may
> result in the loss of future skiing and r

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it may have been the possibility that this question falls afoul of the prohibition against requests for legal advice.  You could edit the question to be more hypothetical and use the third person ("an Airbnb host") rather than the first person ("I") to underscore that you are asking for information about the law rather than individualized advice.

Answer (score 1):

The document you quote does not say "that there are no legal repercussions for breaking Vermont's guidelines". They say that violations of the order do not, alone, provide probable cause to stop a car and question its occupants about their travel. So a LEO may not stop vehicles with out of state plates and ask everyone in the car about where they came from and if they have complied with the order. But if there is another legitimate reason for a stop, such as a clear traffic infraction, such questions could be asked. It says that law enforcement is "encouraged" (not required) to provide education and information, and request voluntary compliance. It does not day that if compliance is defiantly refused, no further action can be taken.

[This government page](https://accd.vermont.gov/covid-19/business/stay-home-stay-safe-sector-specific-guidance#lodging-accommodations) and [ths executive order](https://governor.vermont.gov/sites/scott/files/documents/ADDENDUM%208%20TO%20AMENDED%20AND%20RESTATED%20EXECUTIVE%20ORDER%2001-20.pdf) both  list restrictions in mandatory terms, but neither specifically provides any penalty for failure to comply.